# Multiple Domains to Separate Pages of the Site

Tags: apache, redirect, dns, web, domain-name

I have a client with a single static website. They would like several domain names (around 5) to be connected and redirect to 5 unique pages within the same website. Is there a simple way to have these 5 domains exhibit this behavior, or do we need to create 5 directories that each domain will direct to and then access the rest of the site from there.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Creating folders and mapping domains is an easy option.